# an interesting question related to the borel canteli lemma.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A_n$ be sequence of measurable sets such that $\mu(A_n)$ converges to $0$ but the series of $\mu(A_n)$ diverges to infinity. Then the borel canteli need not hold. How can such a counter example be constructed? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you can look at the typewriter sequence to construct a counterexample

Comment: I think you mean to say that the "series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)$ diverges to infinity? (The phrasing "series of $x_n$" is not common and could be confusing.) Are you asking for an "example" of this, or a counter-example to something. It's not hard to give examples of sequences that converge to zero that yield divergent-to-infinity series. And it's not hard to turn any sequence of non-negative values into an example of, say, interval lengths on the real line...

Comment: Construct a sequence $A_{n, k}$ for $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and $k = 1, \ldots, n$ such that $A_{n,k} = \mathbf{1}_{[\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n}]}$ and then order the $A_{n,k}$  lexicographically $A_{n,k}$ comes first to $A_{m,h}$ if $n < m$ or else if $m = n,$ $k < h.$